# Proof for this sum?

Tags: summation, riemann-zeta

I was messing around with $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\zeta(n) -1)$$ and saw that it approaches 1. After putting it into wolfram, it says it does indeed converge to 1.

Like wise the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\zeta(2n) -1) = \frac {3}{4} $$

I was wondering how these are proven? Or even if I am mistaken in assuming they're proven.

Comment: hint: change the order of summation

Comment: easy close vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty(\zeta(n)-1)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=2}^\infty
\frac1{k^n}.$$
Now reverse the order of summation....